# Multiscroll.js -- is it possible to have CSS3 animations that animate when in view?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, multiscroll.js

I'm new to JS, and not too sure how viewports work. Is it possible to start a css3 animation when the user gets to the third anchor or to a certain section of this plugin? For example, if div #right3 comes into view, how can I start animations within that div?

Answer (score 0):

There's an "afterLoad" callback that accepts anchorLink and index parameters. You could use that to append classes, triggering the animations.

See https://github.com/alvarotrigo/multiscroll.js#afterload-anchorlink-index

Comment: is it possible to get ScrollReveal.js to work with MultiScroll.js?